# Pandas: renaming column alters type of the data

Tags: python, pandas

I am using jupyter Notebook to manipulate a table

I have a data frame with several numerical columns that I renamed using:

```
df1.rename(columns={'FCO_ID_1': 'FCO_ID'}, inplace=True)
df1.rename(columns={'HEIGHT_1': 'H1'}, inplace=True)
df1.rename(columns={'BASAL_AREA': 'BA'}, inplace=True)
```

I then tested the dtype of each column using:

```
print (df1['H1'].dtype)
```

However, when I tested for 'BA',

```
 print (df1['BA'].dtype)
```

I got the following error:

`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'`

I then tested the same column before renaming (from original dataframe df)

```
 print (df['BASAL_AREA'].dtype)
 float64
```

I cannot figure out why renaming changes the data type and why only one column has this problem.

thanks

Comment: impossible to say w/o seeing your data.  check if you have duplicate column names and try to reproduce with a small sample data set and post here

Comment: No duplicate column names. However, there are column names with the name df['BASAL_AREA_1']. That shouldn't be a problem though

Comment: First, you could the rename command with just one dictionary, not 3 lines. Then, could you do `print(df1,columns)` before and after the rename?